# Graphviz (gvc) subgraph attributes not being applied to first subgraph

Tags: c++, graphviz

I am trying to create a set of subgraphs in a graph all with the same attributes. When I try to do this, the attributes get set for all but the first subgraph I try to create:

[image: what I am getting]

As you can see, I am attempting to set the labels to be empty and the widths of the core nodes to be a certain value.

The issue appears to be with my C++ code not generating the dot description I expected it to.

This:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <graphviz/gvc.h>

int main()
{
    Agraph_t* pGraph = agopen("g", Agdirected, NULL);

    for(int i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {

        std::string subGraphNameString = "cluster" + std::to_string(i);
        char* subGraphName = new char[subGraphNameString.length()+1];
        strcpy(subGraphName, subGraphNameString.c_str());

        Agraph_t* pSubGraphi = agsubg(pGraph, subGraphName, 1);
        // sub graph attributes
        // graph
        Agsym_t* goverlap = agattr(pSubGraphi, AGRAPH, "overlap", "false");
        Agsym_t* gstyle = agattr(pSubGraphi, AGRAPH, "style", "dotted");
        // node
        Agsym_t* nlabel = agattr(pSubGraphi, AGNODE, "label", "");
        Agsym_t* nshape = agattr(pSubGraphi, AGNODE, "shape", "circle");
        Agsym_t* nwidth = agattr(pSubGraphi, AGNODE, "width", "0.5");
        Agsym_t* nheight = agattr(pSubGraphi, AGNODE, "height", "0.5");
        // edge
        Agsym_t* elen = agattr(pSubGraphi, AGEDGE, "len", "0.1");

        std::string coreNodeNameString = "core" + std::to_string(i);
        char* coreNodeName = new char[coreNodeNameString.length()+1];
        strcpy(coreNodeName, coreNodeNameString.c_str());

        Agnode_t* coreNodei = agnode(pSubGraphi, coreNodeName, 1);

        for(int j=0; j<=2; j++)
        {
            std::string inputNodeName = "input_node" + std::to_string(j) + "_" + std::to_string(i);
            char* inputNodeNameCStr = new char[inputNodeName.length() + 1];
            strcpy(inputNodeNameCStr, inputNodeName.c_str());

            Agnode_t* inputNodej = agnode(pSubGraphi, inputNodeNameCStr, 1);
            agset(inputNodej, "shape", "point");
            agset(inputNodej, "width", "0.1");
            Agedge_t* inputEdge = agedge(pSubGraphi, inputNodej, coreNodei, 0, 1);
        }

    }

    agwrite(pGraph, stdout);

    agclose(pGraph);

}
```

Produces this:

```
digraph g {
    graph [overlap=false,
        style=dotted
    ];
    node [height=0.5,
        shape=circle,
        width=0.5
    ];
    edge [len=0.1];
    subgraph cluster0 {
        graph [overlap=false,
            style=dotted
        ];
        input_node0_0   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node0_0 -> core0;
        input_node1_0   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node1_0 -> core0;
        input_node2_0   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node2_0 -> core0;
    }
    subgraph cluster1 {
        graph [overlap=false,
            style=dotted
        ];
        node [height=0.5,
            label="",
            shape=circle,
            width=0.5
        ];
        edge [len=0.1];
        input_node0_1   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node0_1 -> core1;
        input_node1_1   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node1_1 -> core1;
        input_node2_1   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node2_1 -> core1;
    }
    subgraph cluster2 {
        graph [overlap=false,
            style=dotted
        ];
        node [height=0.5,
            label="",
            shape=circle,
            width=0.5
        ];
        edge [len=0.1];
        input_node0_2   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node0_2 -> core2;
        input_node1_2   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node1_2 -> core2;
        input_node2_2   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node2_2 -> core2;
    }
    subgraph cluster3 {
        graph [overlap=false,
            style=dotted
        ];
        node [height=0.5,
            label="",
            shape=circle,
            width=0.5
        ];
        edge [len=0.1];
        input_node0_3   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node0_3 -> core3;
        input_node1_3   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node1_3 -> core3;
        input_node2_3   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node2_3 -> core3;
    }
}
```

When I expected it to produce this:

```
digraph g {
    subgraph cluster0 {
        graph [overlap=false,
            style=dotted
        ];
        node [height=0.5,
            label="",
            shape=circle,
            width=0.5
        ];
        edge [len=0.1];
        input_node0_0   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node0_0 -> core0;
        input_node1_0   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node1_0 -> core0;
        input_node2_0   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node2_0 -> core0;
    }
    subgraph cluster1 {
        graph [overlap=false,
            style=dotted
        ];
        node [height=0.5,
            label="",
            shape=circle,
            width=0.5
        ];
        edge [len=0.1];
        input_node0_1   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node0_1 -> core1;
        input_node1_1   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node1_1 -> core1;
        input_node2_1   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node2_1 -> core1;
    }
    subgraph cluster2 {
        graph [overlap=false,
            style=dotted
        ];
        node [height=0.5,
            label="",
            shape=circle,
            width=0.5
        ];
        edge [len=0.1];
        input_node0_2   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node0_2 -> core2;
        input_node1_2   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node1_2 -> core2;
        input_node2_2   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node2_2 -> core2;
    }
    subgraph cluster3 {
        graph [overlap=false,
            style=dotted
        ];
        node [height=0.5,
            label="",
            shape=circle,
            width=0.5
        ];
        edge [len=0.1];
        input_node0_3   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node0_3 -> core3;
        input_node1_3   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node1_3 -> core3;
        input_node2_3   [shape=point,
            width=0.1];
        input_node2_3 -> core3;
    }
}
```

Which produces this image:

[image: what I want]

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong? It is always the first subgraph that fails to be what I want, and SOME of the attributes I want seem to get set at the top level graph, so I am suspecting  that setting up my first subgraph is mutating something internally that then allows my subsequent subgraphs to be set up the way that I want, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am supposed to be doing differently...